# Convert the strings from index [1:] in the List into float. when I'm getting a value error: could not convert string into Float

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a csv file in which the data is in string format. i need to convert the numbers in the row to float.I cannot use any module to read the csv file.The data in the csv file is as follows [['Argentina','23','24.5'......],['America','22.4','23.5'.....].......]

The code i wrote so far is:

````
   with open('life.csv', 'r') as f:
   lines=[line.rstrip() for line in f]# To remove /r/n 
   results = []
   for line in lines:
   words = line.split(',')
   results.append(words)

print (results[1:])```
````

Comment: Can you kindly reformat your question? It's hard to understand what you wanted to know!

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Though I didn't understand your question properly, from the title I assumed you wanted to know, if you have a list of `string` then how can you convert each string element of that list to a floating element.

If that's your question, here is an answer.

Assume you have a list `['12.23', '67.89', '90.12']`

```
my_list = ['12.23', '67.89', '90.12']

for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = float(my_list[i])
```

Now your list will look like this: `[12.23, 67.89, 90.12]`

Also please try to post your question with proper information. Otherwise, it's tough for us to understand it properly!

Comment: The problem is the value at first index should be a strong and the values at the other indexes should be converted into float.

Comment: Try from the 2nd index then. `for i in range(1, len(my_list)):`

Comment: Alright will give it a try and let you know. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is all of the same format as the image you supplied (please don't do that...) (i.e. one 'proper' string, followed by a series of floats stored as strings, you could convert them like this:

```
list1 = [['A', '1.2', '2.3'],
         ['B', '4.5', '6.7']]

list2 = [[x[0]] + list(map(float, x[1:])) for x in list1]
```

This converts the floats and outputs:

```
[['A', 1.2, 2.3], ['B', 4.5, 6.7]]
```

Comment: Won't it be better to do it in place rather allocating a new list? Just saying.

Comment: @sphoenix May well be true, but unless the OP clarifies exactly what, we're just guessing beyond what've provided already.

Comment: And that’s the format of the data in the csv file on which I should work on.

Comment: I genuinely don't understand what you mean by these comments. If you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61874469/edit) your question and add a clear example of the data that you want to convert **as data, not as a picture**, you can get a clear answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry. i have edited the post please have a look.Thanks.